# How to make values to key

Tags: python, dictionary

My List of dict is below

```
file = [{'key': 'apple', 'type':'fruit'},
        {'key': 'beans', 'type':'vegetable'},
        {'key': 'beans', 'type':'fruit'}]
```

Expected out

- value of key is the new key
- value of type is new value

`{'apple': 'fruit', 'beans':['vegetable','fruit']}`

code is below

```
super_dict = {}
for d in file:
    for l, m in d.items():  
        super_dict.setdefault(l, []).append(m)
super_dict
```

My out `{'key': ['apple', 'beans', 'beans'], 'type': ['fruit', 'vegetable', 'fruit']}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of iterating over the `dict.items` take the values

```
super_dict = {}
for d in file:
    l, m = d['key'], d['type']
    super_dict.setdefault(l, []).append(m)
print(super_dict) # {'apple': ['fruit'], 'beans': ['vegetable', 'fruit']}
```

Comment: code is breaking for if i m passing dummy key and values which is not relevant `file = [{'key': 'apple', 'type':'fruit', 'value': 2},
        {'key': 'beans', 'type':'vegetable'},
        {'key': 'beans', 'type':'fruit'}]`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
file = [{'key': 'apple', 'type':'fruit'},
        {'key': 'beans', 'type':'vegetable'},
        {'key': 'beans', 'type':'fruit'}]

super_dict = {}
for d in file:
    k, v = d['key'], d['type']
    if k in super_dict:
        super_dict[k].append(v)
    else:
        super_dict[k] = [v]

print(super_dict)
```

Out:

```
{'apple': ['fruit'], 'beans': ['vegetable', 'fruit']}
```

---

If you *truly* want output as mentioned, i.e. `'fruit'` as a `str`:

```
{'apple': 'fruit', 'beans': ['vegetable', 'fruit']}
```

A slight change could be done:

```py
super_dict = {}
for d in file:
    k, v = d['key'], d['type']
    if k in super_dict:
        item = super_dict[k]
        if isinstance(item, str):
            super_dict[k] = [item, v]
        else:
            item.append(v)
    else:
        super_dict[k] = v
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
file = [{'key': 'apple', 'type':'fruit'},
        {'key': 'beans', 'type':'vegetable'},
        {'key': 'beans', 'type':'fruit'}]

super_dict = {}
newKey = ''
for d in file:
    for l, m in d.items():
        if l=='key': 
            if m not in super_dict:
                super_dict[m]=[]
                newKey=m
        else:
            super_dict[newKey].append(m)
        
print(super_dict)
```

Out:

```
{'apple': ['fruit'], 'beans': ['vegetable', 'fruit']}
```

You need an **' if '** statement to build your dict. Because when make the second iteration with the **' for loop '** your **" l "** value change from **" key "** to **" type "**.

You also need to create a variable  like **' newKey '** to store the key value insde the last iteration to build the new dict.

```
super_dict = {}
newKey = '' 
for d in file:
    for l, m in d.items():
        if l=='key': 
            if m not in super_dict:
                super_dict[m]=[]
                newKey=m
        else:
            super_dict[newKey].append(m)
```

Now you get something like:

```
{'apple': ['fruit'], 'beans': ['vegetable', 'fruit']}
```